# How to preserve timestamp of original file post zip compression?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip, compression

I have a lot of files on our servers which we compression with a filter that only the files older than x days will get compressed.

The zip command compresses the original, makes a filename.zip and removes the original.
This has a small problem that the timestamp changes since the compression job runs after x days.

So when we run files to remove older files (which are by now zip files), not all files get removed since the timestamp has changed from the original file to the compressed file.

I would like to add a condition where while zipping, i want the original timestamp of the file to be retained by the zip archive even though its running at a later date.

One way of doing this would be to

- Get timestamp of each original file with a date command
- Compress the original, remove the original
- Use and insert the earlier stored timestamp to the new zip file using "touch"

I am looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some old file I had:

```
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 120 Sep  5 07:28 foo
```

Zip and redate:

```
$ zip foo.zip foo && touch -d "$(date -R -r foo)" foo.zip
```

Check it out:

```
$ ls -l foo.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 120 Sep  5 07:28 foo.zip
```

Remove the original:

```
$ rm -i foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can unzip a file and preserve the old timestamp from the original time it was created.  Steps to do this are as below:

1. Click on the filename.zip, properties
2. In the General tab, the security says "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer".  Click on the Unblock check box and click OK
3. Extract the file and volla, the extracted file has the datatime stamp when the file was created/modified

Comment: This applies to Windows, not to Linux as is asked for.

Comment: @Nataraja_Sidgal - THANK YOU for this answer re Windows, despite the question being about Linux. The problem also exists in Windows, and this is the only place I've found a workaround, and it works for me. It's crazy that this problem has existed at least since 2011 (https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/bae27baf/) and the 7-Zip gods still haven't fixed it after twelve years! Maybe it's due to a bug deep in the code that no one can find. Anyway, thank you Nataraja for posting this. I upvoted, but it was at -1, so I hope other Windows users will upvote it to get it above 0.